# Does this flow chart appear to be correct? This is my first time creating a flowchart

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, flowchart

## FLOWCHART

Does this flowchart looks alright for a flight arrivals map which shows list of arrivals when we hover over an airport label and shows a separate list of delayed arrivals when we double click an airport label. The first list dissaperas after we double click and then only the delayed arrivals list is displayed.Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG48U.png)

It is my first time crreating a flow chart

Comment: This kind of looks correct but can you elaborate the use case here?